# using Cakephp 2.7.2 how to put userid into $this->User->id for user NOT current user?

Tags: cakephp

part of my code:

```
public function admin_profile($id = 0) {
    $this->set('tab', 'profile');
    $this->set("title_for_layout", " User Profile ");
    $this->layout = "layout_admin";

    $this->User->id = AuthComponent::user('id');

    if (!$this->User->exists()) { ...
```

I want to use **`$id`** and not **`AuthComponent::user('id');`**

I'm trying to setup an **AdminEdit** function so an Admin can add/edit user accounts.

Thanks in advance,
  MajorTomNC

Comment: Sounds like you want `$this->User->id = $id ?: AuthComponent::user('id');` - though it's not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set a user id you do this

```
$this->User->set(array(
     'id' => $id
));
```

But in your case I think the $id parameter is empty.

```
if ($id){
    $this->User->id = $id;
    // or 
    $this->User->set(array(
        'id' => $id
    ));
} else {
    echo "User Id is not set.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Abhishek!  That did it!